Interpretation of the median of submission to first decision
I am an author who submitted my manuscript to a math journal for the first time.
I want to ask for opinions how would one interpret the median of the time to the first decision without knowing the other two quartiles (to know that the manuscript has undergone normal timeline)?
As for my circumstance, the website reports that the median is slightly less than 5 weeks. On the other hand, I did not see/receive any update of the status after the initial submission for over 6 weeks.
The general advice may better be patient, but how long would one worry about this issue if the status kept unchanged?
Thanks in advance!

What are you worrying about here? The median is just that, there must be many that take longer. Are you asking how much longer it will take? Are you asking whether the delay hints at some specific state, such as the submission being exceptionally good/bad?

This is not an "opinion" site, but one where answers are valid or not.

@MisterMiyagi Thank you asking for further clarifications! I have seen some posts back in 2020 where an author's paper was forgotten for 3 months and got unfortunately rejected at that point. I feel like it may well be better for me to receive an earlier feedback rather than possible negligence (due to the relative importance of my work).

Half the papers are claimed to take five weeks or less to a first decision. The other half could be years, actually, especially in math.
The obviously bad and crank papers are probably within that first half. The serious ones take longer, some much longer.
There are too many variables to make any real predictions for an individual paper. Finding reviewers, and reviewers finding the time for review can be highly variable. The more esoteric the paper, the longer, I'd suppose.
Follow up after a month or two if you haven't heard anything. Ask whether there is any information you might find helpful.
Unless you have decisions to make about this paper or other deadlines that depend on it, relax. Bugging the editor won't speed things up. Withdrawing and submitting elsewhere probably won't either. It is unlikely that they have forgotten or that "worry" will be productive.

Thank you very much for your very detailed suggestions!

According to this post https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a, I have a feeling / believe that my manuscript hasn't been assigned editors yet (at least to the associate editors?). So what might be some reasons/factors in this situation? Thanks again!
